# Route Angular can can’t be reached

Tags: angular, angular-router

My route rules are:

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: "", component: HomeComponent },
    { path: '/register', component: AppComponent },
    { path: "**", redirectTo: "/" }
];
```

I tried to open URL:

```
https://localhost:80/register
```

It redirects me to `/` page.

Comment: Can you add your HTML code as well?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Remove / from Route path.**

```
{ path: 'register', component: AppComponent }
```

Comment: It still redirects to `/` after removing slash

Comment: It is not possible. Check whether url is correctly spelled.

Comment: I have left only one rule: ` { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },` It also redirect to main `/`

Comment: Can  you give a try commenting `{ path: "**", redirectTo: "/" }` line in your code

Comment: I have commented, then call `/home` url

Comment: what happened..?

Comment: I think problem in app.module in line: `  bootstrap: [AppComponent]`

Comment: may be. your component of 'register' path is also  `AppComponent`. that may be the problem

Answer (score 1):

Hi the correct way to use it like this.

```
{ path: 'register', component: AppComponent }
```